# java.lang.ClassCastException in hibernate while calling session.getUniqueResult or session.get

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8

`Class cast exception` while calling `session.getUniqueResult`. I have tried with `session.get` but ended in the same error.

From Logs

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sample.functional.role.model.Role cannot be cast to com.sample.functional.role.model.Role
    at com.sample.functional.role.dao.RoleDaoImpl.getRole(RoleDaoImpl.java:84) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.sample.functional.role.dao.RoleDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8ae202bf.invoke(<generat
```

I do not understanding why hibernate is giving the above error.

Role Hibernate mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "roleid")
    private String roleID;


    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb",name="privileges")
    private List<Privilege>  privileges;


    @Column(name="rolename")
    private String rolename;

    @Column(name = "emailid")
    private String emailID;

    @Column(name = "isadmin")
    private boolean isAdmin;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private boolean status;




    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRoleID() {
        return roleID;
    }

    public void setRoleID(String roleID) {
        this.roleID = roleID;
    }

    public String getRolename() {
        return rolename;
    }

    public void setRolename(String rolename) {
        this.rolename = rolename;
    }

    public String getEmailID() {
        return emailID;
    }

    public void setEmailID(String emailID) {
        this.emailID = emailID;
    }

    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return isAdmin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(boolean isAdmin) {
        this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
    }

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public String getUpdatedBy() {
        return updatedBy;
    }

    public void setUpdatedBy(String updatedBy) {
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    }

    public Long getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Long createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Long getUpdatedDate() {
        return updatedDate;
    }

    public void setUpdatedDate(Long updatedDate) {
        this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
    }

    public boolean isIsrecActive() {
        return isrecActive;
    }

    public void setIsrecActive(boolean isrecActive) {
        this.isrecActive = isrecActive;
    }

    public List<Privilege> getPrivileges() {
        return privileges;
    }

    public void setPrivileges(List<Privilege> privileges) {
        this.privileges = privileges;
    }



}
```

getRole method:

```
public Role getRole(String roleId) {
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            String queryString = "from Role where roleID = :roleID "/* +"and isrecactive = 'true'" */;
            Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
            query.setParameter("roleID", roleId);
            Role role =(Role) query.uniqueResult();
            session.close();
            return role;
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            log.error("Exception {} " + ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's impossible, given what we know, to tell you how to fix the issue. But what this shows is that Hibernate loads the Role class using a ClassLoader that is different from the ClassLoader used by your repository. You have probably added the entities in the classpath of your web server (which also contains Hibernate), and to the classpath of your application.

Comment: I thought so, but I am seeing this problem today. I am running as a spring boot application (standalone) in intellij. I am checking if the same classes added through jars now.  But the similar question in stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273791/java-lang-classcastexception-in-hibernate-uniqueresult

Comment: I have tried removing the class and check. but it is giving `compile time error`, as I **remove** the class from intellij. I think this should conclude there is only one `Role` class exists in class path

Comment: Can you make a proof-of-concept project that replicates this behaviour?